# Hide game object in other scenes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've used this code to stop destroying a specific game object. The problem is when i change the scene that contain this object to another different scene ,the game object still showing even in different scene...
How to only show the game object in its scene.
I hope that I clearly specify my problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class DontDestroy : MonoBehaviour {
 void Awake() {
     DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
     if(FindObjectsOfType(GetType()).Length > 1) {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of putting a copy of the object in every scene when you are designing what about creating a pre-load scene that you load only once that has all your don't distroy on load objects in it. See this post in the unity fourms https://forum.unity.com/threads/preload-scene-always-or-it-depends.513349/

Comment: @adelkanso, did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
m_Scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
sceneName = m_Scene.name;
//Do logic by checking the specific scene you want
if (sceneName == YOUR_SCENE) {
    this.gameObject.SetActive(false);  //Set false to hide, true to show

}
```