# Load scene additively and destroy it later

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes- MainScene and InfoScene. The user is in the MainScene during the beginning and then presses a button to load the InfoScene. The MainScene should not be visible when the user is in InfoScene. The InfoScene is then destroyed and then the MainScene becomes active. Now the thing is, I want the user to come back to the last position he was in, during the MainScene and destroy the InfoScene.

So is it possible to keep the MainScene active in the background while we are in the InfoScene and then destroy the InfoScene to come back to the last state in the MainScene? If so, is it through the Additive Loading?

```
SceneManager.LoadScene ("InfoScene", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Comment: In short yes ... that's the purpose of `LoadSceneMode.Additive` ...

Comment: But when I do Additive Loading, the previous scene is still visible. Is there a way to hide it along with the camera? So that the user is immersed into the 2nd scene only.

Comment: There is no trivial (= built-in) way, no. You can get all root objects of that other scene(s) and set them all to `SetActive(false)` and reactivate them later.

Comment: Does this answer your question [Hide game object in other scenes in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60130315/hide-game-object-in-other-scenes-in-unity) ?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah I think hiding gameObjects is the only way. I was trying to see if we can deactivate a complete scene and then activate it again but looks like it is not possible.